# Can I use ZeroMQ with HAProxy, a software-based load balancer?

Tags: tcp, load-balancing, zeromq, haproxy, pgm-protocol

HAProxy is a software-based load balancer that supports http and tcp distribution. If I use ZeroMQ with pragmatic multicast enabled (pgm), will the use of HAProxy as an intermediary between zmq peers conflict with pgm, or should I use hardware-based load balancer, like F5?

Answer (score 2):

No. PGM (IANA IP protocol number 113) isn't TCP (IANA IP protocol number 6). HAProxy is an HTTP and TCP load balancer.